# Tenant level configuration changes using SPOL Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, powershell

We can import the search configuration for a site collection to replicate the search settings. Can we do the same for tenant level search settings? Or can we change individual property of search configuration for eg 
**Search Center URL**   using SharePoint online management shell?

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlets for SharePoint Online are very limited and do not allow you to set search settings:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx

You can look towards CSOM solutions on Technet Gallery or [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=&sortBy=PageViews&tagName=%2CSharepoint%2CSearch%2C&licenses=%7C&refinedSearch=true). There are even some solutions that include additional SPO cmdlets, but I am not familiar with any search-related CMDLETS -> so scripting.

From the user interface you can modify the tenant level Search Settings under this link:
https://TENANTNAMECHANGEPLS-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/searchadmin/TA_SearchAdministration.aspx

Comment: It's worth adding for reference, that in that user interface, it does give the ability to export/import search configuration.

Comment: Can we use Powershell with CSOM to set tenant level settings.

Comment: can we do any tenant level changes(search) using SPOL powershell + CSOM or is it just for site collection level search config changes?